# How to avoid td width expanding when it wrapped with enabled overflow and big div inside

Tags: css

I have a table with 2 columns, the first one should be 25% wide width and and 2nd one should be 75% wide.

In the 2nd column, sometimes there's big content, therefore, I made a div inside with `overflow: scroll` and inside that wrap div I made the big content, but from some reason, it expands the full 2nd td column, an example:

```css
table {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}

.col1 {
    width: 25%;
    background: green;
}

.col2 {
    width: 75%;
    background: skyblue;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.big_content {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td class="col1">Hello<td>
      <td class="col2">World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="col1">big field<td>
      <td class="col2">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="big_content">some big content here</div>
        </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I avoid the 2nd column from being expanded due to the big content it has? because I wrapped that big content inside another div (`.wrap`) that has overflow: scroll

Comment: You could try using [`table-layout: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `table-layout:fixed` for table:

```css
table {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed
}

.col1 {
    width: 25%;
    background: green;
}

.col2 {
    width: 75%;
    background: skyblue;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.big_content {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td class="col1">Hello<td>
      <td class="col2">World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="col1">big field<td>
      <td class="col2">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="big_content">some big content here</div>
        </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```